# Visual Studio Code (VSCode) Terminal Creation For Specific Environments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scrapy

I'm fairly new to programming and newer to VSCode.

I'm trying to create terminals for use with specific python environments.

For instance, I have scrapy installed in a conda environment.

Somehow, I have a terminal open that shows the 'In' and 'Out' correctly:

[Showing the 'scrapy' terminal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxO9U.png)

If I use Ctrl + Shift + P and select Python: Create Terminal, I get this instead:

[using scrapy with Ctrl+ Shift+ P 'Python: Create Terminal' and Ctrl+ Shift+ P Python: Select Interpretor set to 'scrapy'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOLG7.png)

Notice how the second picture is still using the scrapy library, but is missing the indicators found in the first picture.

This behavior makes sense to me since 'Python' != 'scrapy', but I have no idea how I started the 'scrapy' terminal or how to do it again. I believe VSCode brought up the 'scrapy' terminal automatically when I switched environments to 'scrapy' using Ctrl+ Shift+ P Python: Select Interpretor.

There is no option that I can find in Ctrl+ Shift+ P for 'scrapy: Create Terminal'

I apologize for the convoluted question as I'm barely sure what I am asking. I hope this makes sense.

Note: I just restarted VSCode to replicate the steps that opened the 'scrapy' terminal for me to no avail. As you can see in the picture below, I have the correct environment selected, but it is defaulting to powershell (which is my default interpreter).

[VSCode defaulting to powershell when 'scrapy' interpreter selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqkqr.png)

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you somehow got your settings tangled up such that you had `scrapy` specified as your Python implementation.

And if you want the `In` and `Out` labels, that comes from IPython, so you can launch that in a terminal and get that experience back.

Comment: Okay, thank you. The more I looked into this myself, the more I was thinking the same thing. I no longer have the 'In' and 'Out' in the Anaconda Prompt either, so something is wrong. Everything else works though...I'll have to reinstall the env at some point.